# Not receiving FCM messages when app is killed and in "Optimised" battery mode

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send FCM messages to my device. I receive them correctly when app is in background or foreground. However, when my app is killed, I don't receive notifications if it is in the default "Optimised" battery usage mode. When I set my app's battery mode to "Not optimised", I receive notifications correctly even when app is killed.

And yes, I've tried sending FCM messages and FCM notifications with "High" Priority.

All other apps (WhatsApp, Facebook etc.) on my device are in "Optimised" mode yet they receive push notifications even when they're killed.

I'm using OnePlus 5T (Android 8.1.0). Can anyone explain why is this happening in my app specifically?

I've gone through [Optimize for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)
, but I've heard that Google will reject your app if you're using REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS for any of the reasons except those mentioned within the [Whitelisting Cases](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases). Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Do you have any update on your problem? I am facing the exact same situation and really do not know how to solve this other than kindly asking the user to set my app's battery mode to "Not optimized". If you have found a better solution in the meantime, I would be really grateful if you would share it with me.